# How To Increment A Number By 1 On Window Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, events, scroll

I have a type of progress tracker sitting fixed on the side of my page and as you scroll, I want the line to gain height (in percentages) as the user scrolls down the page. I am having trouble getting the height to increase by just one as the user scrolls. Here is my current code.

JS

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
 var number = 0; /* I'd like to increment this by one on scroll */
 // Only start the process when the first section comes into view
 if($("#progress-tracker-nav li").hasClass('active-section')) {
  number++; /* I'd like to increment this by one on scroll */
  $(".progress-line").css('height', number + '%');
 }
})
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using a counter on the scroll function 1 that will be overly complex and inaccurate because you have to account for when they scroll up as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you define `number` inside the scroll event.
You will need to define it outside in order for the amount to be incremented.

```
var number = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(){
  number++;
});
```

The current way you are doing it means `number` is reset to 0 each time the event fires.

Comment: OP: Mine and Alexandru-lonut's answers are the same but his was first. If you accept one as the answer, please make it his.

Comment: @CarlMarkham this does not answer the OP's question.  This will not give the percentage of of the screen height. In fact you need no counter what so ever.

Answer (score 5):

You have to declare `number` variable outside of the `scroll` event handler, because every time when `scroll` event is fired, the variable value is `refreshed`.

In your current code, you assign every time `0` value for `number` variable.

```js
var number = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(){ 
  number++;
  $("#number").text(number + '%');
})
```

```css
body{
  height:1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="number"></div>
```

Comment: This does NOT work, if you scroll up and down the percentage still goes up

Answer (score 1):

To increase the number on scroll down, you can do

```
var lastScrollPosition = $(document).scrollTop();
var number = 0;
$(window).on('scroll', function(e) {
    if($(document).scrollTop() > lastScrollPosition ){
        number++;
    }
})
```

Likewise, you can replace the `>` to `<` if you need to reduce the number when user scroll up.

If you want to reduce the height on scroll up and increase the height on scroll down, you can do this as well.

```
var lastScrollPosition = $(document).scrollTop();
var initalHeight = 100;
$(window).on('scroll', function(e) {
    $(".progress-line").css('height', ((100/ (100 - $(document).scrollTop()/$(document).height()) + '%');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

These events will fire VERY frequently, so you might want to move your selectors into a closure so they don't have to be recalculated each time:

```
function registerScrollEvent() {
 // get reference to DOM elements once since the scroll event fires frequently
 var number = 0,
  elNav = $("#progress-tracker-nav li"),
  elProgress = $(".progress-line");
 $(window).scroll(function(){
  // Only start the process when the first section comes into view
  if(elNav.hasClass('active-section')) {
   number++;
   elProgress.css('height', number + '%');
  }
 })
}
```

Also, be aware of issues on IOS related to scroll events only firing after the scrolling completes:

`https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16202`

Also, not sure how you are planning on resetting. The scroll events will fire whether scrolling up or down so the number is just going to keep increasing. Is that what you want?

Comment: Lol? Apparently some do?

Answer (score 0):

I think the height of the progress bar should be relative to the `scrollTop` of the window divided by the maximum scroll possible (the height of the document minus the height of the window). Using this formula:

```
percentage_of_height_of_progress_bar = 100 * scroll_top_of_window / (height_of_document - height_of_window);
```

**Example:**

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var percent = $(document).scrollTop() / ($(document).height() - $(window).height()) * 100;
  $(".progress").css('width', percent + '%');
})
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}

.progress {
  position: fixed;
  width: 0%;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><div class="progress"></div></div>
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer, as this follows what can be assumed to be the most accurate depiction of what the user wants.

Comment: @johnny5 And what makes me very angry is that people think that downvoting alone is usefull. I think SO should oblige downvoters to leave a comment!

Comment: Yeah and there should be a review for down votes, because if there comment isn't valid their downvote shouldn't count

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
    height: 4000px;
    width: 4000px;
}
          
.main {
    position: fixed;
}
```

```js
var myMain = document.getElementById('main');
var number = 0;
    
myMain.onclick = function () {    
    'use strict';
        
    number += 100;
    window.scrollTo(0, number);
        
    console.log(window.scrollY);
};
```