# Change opacity as you scroll, based on height

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple sections on a page. Each has an overlay that starts out at `1` opacity.  I would like it to reduce opacity as you scroll with it reaching `0` when the bottom of the element is at the top of the page.

I based this code on another question here, and it *almost* works for one, but I want to do this for multiple elements on the page and that's where things break down. When I try it, each subsequent element starts out less opaque and it's even worse if the window size is reduced.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var homeTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var height = $(window).height() / 2;

    $('#splashback-home').css({
        'opacity': ((height - homeTop) / height)
    });
});
```

How can I make this dynamic for say any element with the `.splashback` class?

I'm thinking something like this?

```
    $('.splashback').each(function () {
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var thisTop = $(this).offset().top;
        var thisHeight = $(this).height();
        newOpacity = ???
        if (newOpacity > 1) newOpacity = 1;
        $(this).css({'opacity': newOpacity});
    });
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140800/jquery-trigger-when-2-3s-of-div-are-in-viewport/29142018#29142018

Comment: Might be of some help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42354638/6647153

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're close - you need to take the element's offset into account for each `.splashback`:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var homeTop = $(window).scrollTop();

  $(".splashback").each(function() {
    var height = $(this).height();
    var offset = $(this).offset().top;
    var opacity = (height - homeTop + offset) / height;

    $(this).css("opacity", opacity);
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  background: red;
  height: 1000px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.splashback {
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Some div (will not fade)</div>
<div class="splashback">Some div splashback 1</div>
<div class="splashback">Some div splashback 2</div>
<div>Some div (will not fade)</div>
```

Comment: @Scott I'm not sure who downvoted you, it's a well-written question.  Also you have a great name.

Comment: Just to mention that if someone wants just, for example, to hide "hero" section, in this example red `div`, you can delete `var offset`, just for little lighter code :-)
@Scott Thank you for great example